# how to get loaded url from picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

I am using picasso library for set marker with image on google map api. But i need to get loaded drawable which loaded from picasso.

I tried this but its not returning the url which loaded from picasso

```
Target target = new Target() {
          @Override
          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

          }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

        @Override


     public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the URL from Picasso *after* the drawable has loaded ([Picasso.LoadedFrom](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.LoadedFrom.html) will only tell you whether the image was loaded from *DISK*, *MEMORY* or *NETWORK*).

But since you need to specify the URL when you tell Picasso to **.load()** the image, you can simply store the URL somewhere and use it later on.

If your actual goal is to load a custom marker icon from a remote URL into a Google Maps marker, here is how to do it using an ad-hoc ImageView:

```
private void loadImageFromUrlIntoMarker(final String url, final Marker marker) {
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(iv, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            try {
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not load image into marker.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not load image from " + url);
        }
    });
}
```

The `try { ... } catch { ... }` is important, as the marker might be invalid when the drawable becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

basic usage of picasso

```
    Picasso.with(context).load(my_url).into(my_view);
```

and import the library using gradle

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: I am not looking for that :) i need to get "my_url" after the image loaded.

Comment: where is the url coming from

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you asking this question because you need an url to load image with `Picasso` . You can create a function basically like :

```
public void loadimage(final String loadingUrl){
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(loadingUrl).into(yourimageview, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.v("picasso","i successfully created image, here is url : "+loadingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I will show the picture of users on the google map. So i am saving the loaded url and the coordinant of users in the hashmap.(HashMap<"Coordinant", "Picture">)

So i need the url which is loaded from picasso for every user. Then i am gonna set the picture as marker by getting picture from hashmap with using the coordinant key.

I user to universalimageloader to achive it. Because this library is returning the image after the loading process. But i am still wondering how to achive it by using picasso.

Comment: Can you post your full method to determine how you are using Picasso. If you dont have any url's when loading images , u must use bitmap or drawables sth. Then you can convert them to base64 and save string key values. Please update your full code and i will help you

Comment: i saw this comment right now sorry.I think thats acceptable. I will try and inform you. Thanks.